# Can I grant lambda access to other accounts using Organization Unit IDs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-organizations

I want to create a lambda that will exist in one central account and that will get invoked by other accounts within my [Organization](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_introduction.html).  I know it is possible to grant access for another individual account to invoke a lambda using a [resource policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html#permissions-resource-xaccountinvoke), but can I grant access to all accounts in my Organization using Organization Unit IDs somehow?  If so, how?

Ideally I want to make it so as new accounts get added in my Organization they will automatically have access to invoke the lambda without requiring me to update the policy and grant them access via the individual account ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this can be done using a resource policy on the lambda function with a condition that specifies the `aws:PrincipalOrgID`, such as

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:098765432109:function:My_Example_Function",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "o-myorgidexample"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `Principal` part of the resource policy, you can only provide AWS accounts, users, roles etc but no organizational units. However, there is a condition called [`aws:PrincipalOrgPaths`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-principalorgpaths) which I think can help you achieve what you want.

Comment: That looks promising, so I tried, but I don't see any way via the console or API to specify a condition for the policy.  Ex. [the boto3 API call](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.add_permission).  It seems like the API and console take inputs and construct the policy from those inputs, but they don't have an input for condition.